# AngularJS not reading JSON properly

Tags: json, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I created an application so that it can read JSON file data using AngularJS HTTP Get method but I am not getting the result in the table as expected.
Below is the code:

**HomeController**

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Mvc;

 namespace CategoryWebApplication.Controllers
 {
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
  }
}
```

**The View : Index.cshtml**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Angular JS Includes</title>
<style>
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid grey;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    table tr:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }

    table tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Sample Category Application</h2>
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="categoryController">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Category ID</th>
            <th>Category Name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="category in categories">
            <td>{{ category.CategoryID }}</td>
            <td>{{ category.CategoryName }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<script>
    function categoryController($scope, $http) {
        var url = "http://localhost:4425/Category.txt";
        $http.get(url).success(function (response) {
            $scope.categories = response;
        });
    }
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js">    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the JSON in the text file category is the following:
**Category.txt**

```
[
{
"CategoryID" : 1,
"CategoryName" : "Blood"
},
{
"CategoryID" : 2,
"CategoryName" : "Urine"
},
{
"CategoryID" : 3,
"CategoryName" : "Saliva"
},
{
"CategoryID" : 4,
"CategoryName" : "Serum"
},
{
"CategoryID" : 5,
"CategoryName" : "Hair"
},
{
"CategoryID" : 6,
"CategoryName" : "Nail"
},
{
"CategoryID" : 7,
"CategoryName" : "Tissue"
}

]
```

Below is the result I am getting in the browser

[image]

Comment: Did you specify the header to be `Content-type: application/json`?

Comment: @Joy, no, I did not. Where should I specify it?

Comment: Can you log response and see if it is defined or not

Comment: Something like: `$http.get({ method: 'get', url: '', headers: {Content-type: 'application/json'})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was facing  a similar kind of trouble, server correctly sending the json data but angular was not reading it properly. After research of several hours came across to JSON.parse() and bang it worked like a charm. More reference: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Answer (score 2):

Change file extension from `txt` to `json` (`Category.json`).

And change your javascript code to this.
Define module and controller:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp");
app.controller("categoryController", function($scope,$http){
  var url = "http://localhost:4425/Category.json";
  $http.get(url).success(function (response) {
     $scope.categories = response;
  });
})
```

Markup:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="categoryController">
```

Here i have made a live [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/A7RCdXMUst2pZF8cN6K2?p=preview), so you can see how it is working.Plus you should go through [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) of angular controllers.

Comment: @mudaseer, I have changed the file extension but the same result appears.

Comment: @Loic as jax mentioned, check if you have changed file name in call too, and please have a look how controller and module has been defined. I have edited answer.

Comment: Yes, I did change  the http to "localhost:4425/Category.json", but still the same result. I will try changing the controller and module.

Comment: @Loic i have added demo link and documentation link to my answer, so you can see things in more detail.

Comment: @mudasserajaz, thank you for your help and the demo.

Comment: i was facing  a similar kind of trouble, server correctly sending the json data but angular was not reading it properly. After research of several hours came across to JSON.parse() and bang it worked like a charm. More reference: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp